# No aparecen estadísticas en Google Analytics después de incluir la etiqueta en mi codigo

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, django, google-analytics

Puse una etiqueta de Google Analytics en [el encabezado de mi sitio web](https://github.com/antoinecomp/django3-personal-portfolio/blob/main/portfolio/templates/portfolio/base.html):

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-V51YR2QF7N"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-V51YR2QF7N');
</script>
```

Pero incluso después de volver a cargar el sitio web en mi entorno de desarrollo integrado de pythonanywhere, todavía no aparecen estadísticas.

Comment: ¿Hay algún error en la consola al ejecutar este código?

Comment: @jachguate Si un 400 ... No sé si es a causa del tag javaascript de Google Analytics

Comment: En la consola del navegador... la petición no es a tu servidor, por lo que no veo como tu servidor podría registrar algo relacionado a esa llamada...

Comment: En efecto senor @jachguate Pienso que solo GA registra algo.